# A strange problem about ros::init()

Tags: roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I encounter a really strange problem about ros::init(). I successfully compile the whole program, and of course the ros::init function is called at the first line of the "main program" as usual, then the creation of ros::NodeHandle is called. But when I run the program, the ros tells me that "You must call ros::init() before creating the first NodeHandle", then stops the program. And I also checked the related source code which says it is because the ros initiation fails (well, naturally), but why? Can anyone provide some clues? Really appreciate!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12962/a-strange-problem-about-ros::init()/) by [Mike Gao](https://answers.ros.org/users/1629/mike-gao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2012-02-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-02-09**:
Take the first/minimal example from the tutorials and that should work. You can compare it to your code and see what's different. Without any more information, people can just guess what you are doing.

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-02-09**:
By "main program" do you mean `main()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you have any ROS-related variables outside of `main`? For example, when I write a small node (too small be rolled up inside a class), I usually end up with global variables; `main` initializes them, and then my callback uses them.

But: global variables get constructed before `main` is called, so if you're using something that refers to a NodeHandle internally, you'll get this error. I almost always get it with `tf::TransformListener`, just because I forget that it's going to happen.

The solution is to store a pointer (I generally use a `boost::shared_ptr<T>`) to that object, not just a raw object, and then fill the pointer in in `main` after you call `ros::init()`.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2012-03-02**:
That is my problem. Can you give more details on your solution? Thanks.

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-03-02**:
All of my ROS-aware global variables are declared as boost::shared_ptrs, rather than just objects; those pointers get set in main(), *after* ros::init().

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2014-11-25**:
Could you provide a code sample? Thank you.

**Comment by [feixiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/23311/feixiao/) on 2015-08-31**:
i tryed your suggessed`boost::shared_ptr<Robot> tars(new Robot());`it doesn`t work:^(

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's possible that you have some sort of global variable that either is a nodeHandle, or contains a nodeHandle, which is initialized before main() starts.

Are you passing the appropriate arguments to ros::init() ?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-02-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@Mac is exactly right. I'm adding another answer only to suggest another common design pattern: use a C++ class to defer variable initialization. The example below includes a `TransformBroadcaster` private variable, which will create a NodeHandle. It gets initialized when `Publisher publisher` is created.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <tf2_ros/transform_broadcaster.h>
#include <tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/Imu.h>

class Publisher
{
private:

  tf2_ros::TransformBroadcaster tf_broadcaster_;
  ros::Subscriber imu_sub_;

  void imuCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImuConstPtr &msg)
  {
    geometry_msgs::TransformStamped imu_tf;
    imu_tf.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
    imu_tf.header.frame_id = "base_link";
    imu_tf.child_frame_id = "imu_link";
    imu_tf.transform.rotation = msg->orientation;
    tf_broadcaster_.sendTransform(imu_tf);
  }

public:

  Publisher(ros::NodeHandle& nh_priv)
  {
    imu_sub_ = nh_priv.subscribe<sensor_msgs::Imu>("/imu/data", 10, &Publisher::imuCallback, this);
  }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "tf_publish");
  ros::NodeHandle nh("");
  ros::NodeHandle nh_priv("~");
  Publisher publisher(nh_priv);
  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) with karma: 1247 on 2018-01-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-19**:
Should your `{` and `}` be `(` and `)`, respectively?

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2018-01-19**:
Ah, I was having fun w/ C++14. I changed it to parens. :-)